# How to return all records if parameter is null

Tags: sql-server

The following is my *SP*:

```
Alter PROCEDURE GetList 
(

@FromDate date = null,
@ToDate date = null

)
AS

Select * FROM CallList c
Where c.CallDate > @FromDate and c.CallDate < @ToDate
```

If there was no passed date filter, I want to get all the records.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of viable options:

You could set `@FromDate` and `@ToDate` to be equal to a very early or very late date respectively they're NULL.

You could use sp_executesql and construct a dynamic query string w/ parameters as needed e.g.

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM CallList C WHERE 1 = 1 '

IF @FromDate IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' AND C.CallDate > @xFromDate'
END

IF @ToDate IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += ' AND C.CallDate < @xToDate'
END

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, N'@xFromDate DATETIME, @xToDate DATETIME', @xFromDate = @FromDate, @xToDate = @ToDate
```

This latter approach performs better than using ORs all over the place, as queries that include ORs invariably end up getting optimized very badly - they might work well for a certain set of parameters but are generally not one-size-fits-all.

Comment: +1 for correctly building a SQL string with parameters in it then using sp_executesql - So many people just inject the values and ignore the consequences of that.

Comment: Upvote for emphasizing the importance of not injecting the values.  :)

Comment: While I think you do have the correct methodology with dynamic SQL, its the sledge hammer approach when all you need is a hammer. Dynamic SQL should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @N8 - True - it does lead to difficult to maintain code, for this simple query perhaps it's overkill.  If CallList has millions of rows, it might be worth it - a few thousand, then probably not.  For stored procedures (typically search sprocs) that take umpteen parameters which may or may not be NULL, dynamic SQL is often a life-saver.

Comment: heh, oh I HATE procedures like that as well! I am right there with you though, by the 10th parameter, it just becomes a nightmare to manage. the hardest thing to work around is the darn parameter sniffing!

Answer (score 16):

You can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM CallList c
WHERE (c.CallDate > @FromDate OR @FromDate IS NULL) AND 
      (c.CallDate < @ToDate OR @ToDate IS NULL)
```

This also leaves you open to the possibility to leaving one of the dates null and not the other.

Comment: Watch out for OR-heavy queries - they have a tendency to bite.

Answer (score 6):

you'd do the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM CallList AS C
WHERE (@FromDate IS NULL OR c.CallDate > @FromDate)
AND (@ToDate IS NULL OR c.CallDate < @ToDate)
```

Comment: basically, we are saying, if the parameter is null, ignore it. Otherwise, it must meet the criteria following the OR

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CallList c
WHERE
    ( @FromDate is null AND @ToDate is null ) OR
    ( @FromDate is null AND c.CallDate < @ToDate ) OR
    ( @ToDate is null AND c.CallDate > @FromDate) OR
    ( c.CallDate > @FromDate AND c.CallDate < @ToDate )
```

---

Also, if you were looking for the intersection between the two periods, do not forget to select the later *FromDate* and the earlier *ToDate*.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic sql is complie every time, so prevent to use dynamic sql

```
    select * from calllist As c
    where (c.CallDate < @ToDate or @ToDate is null)
and  (c.CallDate > @FromDate or @FromDate is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @BgnDate date,
 @EndDate date

SELECT @BgnDate = MIN(c.CallDate),  @EndDate = MIN(c.CallDate) FROM CallList

Select * FROM CallList c
Where c.CallDate > ISNULL(@FromDate,@BgnDate) 
and c.CallDate < ISNULL(@ToDate,@EndDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `BETWEEN` (short hand for less than or equals to and greater than or equals to):

```
declare @ToDate varchar(12)=null,
    @FromDate varchar(12)=null

select * from calllist As c where c.CallDate between 
CONVERT(datetime, isnull(@ToDate,c.CallDate)) 
and CONVERT(datetime,isnull(@FromDate,c.CallDate))
```

Comment: If possible provide some extra information (other than just the SQL) to explain why this is better/different from other answers, thanks.

Comment: Between is shorthand of LTE and GTE, Between translate into GTE and LTE during Query compilation,So i think execution time should be same,i just give a short answer on it