# How to ignore condition, if parameter value = "ALL"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I found this link

[How to return all records if parameter is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6131542/how-to-return-all-records-if-parameter-is-null)

I need,

**Ignore the parameter/condition just as above, when the parameter value is ALL.**

How to achieve this.

Info below,  TASK : instead of null there should be ignore if parameter = ALL

```
Declare @psqluid varchar(15) = 'admin'
Declare @psqlstartdate datetime = '06/01/2010'
Declare @psqlenddate datetime = '06/28/2012'
Declare @psqlcompany varchar(45)
Declare @psqlapplication varchar(10) = 'APP2'
Declare @psqlprogram varchar(10)= 'PROG1'
SELECT * FROM [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS] 
WHERE (@psqluid IS NULL  OR [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsUserID]=@psqluid) 
AND [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsDate] >= @psqlstartdate 
AND [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsDate] <= @psqlenddate 
AND (@psqlcompany IS NULL OR [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsCompany] = @psqlcompany) 
AND [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsApplication] = @psqlapplication 
AND [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsProgram] = @psqlprogram
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF @param!="ALL"
BEGIN
  SET @Sql += 'Condition'
END
```

Isn't works?

added:

```
WHERE @psqluid = "ALL" OR [TMSFINAL].[dbo].[TMTMS].[tmsUserID]=@psqluid ...
```

Comment: this may work, i want a solution which does not require join strings as shown in the IGNORING NULL PARAMETER link. any thing like that?

Comment: I think I need more concret info about your procedure to be able to do it

Comment: Info added, how to accomplish this using ignore if paramater = "ALL"

Comment: Thankyou, just a syntax error, single quotes WHERE @psqluid = 'ALL', Thankyou